# How do I concatenate 2 strings in NSIS

Tags: string, nsis, string-concatenation, concatenation

How do I concatenate 2 strings in  NSIS?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
StrCpy $1 "one string"

StrCpy $2 " second string"

MessageBox MB_OK "$1$2"
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want to concatenate using the same variable you can do something like this:

```
StrCpy $1 "ABC"

StrCpy $1 "$1123"

DetailPrint $1
```

output is "ABC123"

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the variables can be placed just next to string literals

Answer (score 15):

```
StrCpy $1 "Hello"

StrCpy $2 "World"

StrCpy $3 "$1 $2"

DetailPrint $3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to split up one long string over multiple lines, just use the `\` inside the quotes:

```
MessageBox MB_OK "Alright, Mr. User you are done here, so you can go ahead and \ 
stop reading this message box about now."
```